# Laravel : How save array in database?

Tags: arrays, laravel, database, controller, pivot

I need your help because I can't save array from form in the pivot table. If someone can show me how because this is going to drive me crazy.

So I have a exam form with input number in foreach and which has a dynamic name.
And I have two total results to.

This is my data form :
[image: Screen of DD]

I want save my input number question in pivot table and the results on another table.
For the result it's ok but it's for save in pivot table I have a problem.

Thanks to help me.

In my controller I make this :

```
$data = $request->all();
foreach($data as $question_id => $answer_id){
            $result = new PratiqueReponse();
            $result->question_id = $question_id;
            $result->answer_id = $answer_id;
            $result->save();
        }
```

But not working.

Comment: You need to provide more details to enable anyone to help you properly. 
Otherwise, this is just guessing. What is your model structure here? Which one is the pivot you mentioned? What does "But not working" mean? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not share much information, so i can only guess but i think you should save to db like this:

```
$data = $request->all();
foreach($data['questions'] as $question_id => $answer_id){
    $result = new PratiqueReponse();
    $result->question_id = $question_id;
    $result->answer_id = $answer_id;
    $result->save();
}
```

you need to loop trough questions, not the whole array.